# Evaluate a Column with SELECT CASE in mySQL and Returns three columns as Result

Tags: mysql, select, case, multiple-columns

Hi I have a mySQL Table with these five columns

1) ValidationSTS
2) Comprobante_Tipo_Comprobante
3) Comprobante_Subtotal
4) Impuesto_Trasladado
5) Comprobante_Total

So, I need to Evaluate first ValidationSTS, when equals "Cancelado", then Multiply by Zero, in order to get Zero as Result
Case Else then pass to a nested SELECT CASE.

In that nested SELECT CASE I eval "Comprobante_Tipo_Comprobante",and then eval two cases: "ingreso" and "egreso".
When Case equals "ingreso", the result would be the column "Comprobante_Subtotal"
When Case equals "egreso", the result would be the column "Comprobante_Subtotal" in negative.

So that's my code and returns one column as Result:

```html
SELECT
CASE ValidationSts WHEN 'Cancelado' THEN 0*Comprobante_Subtotal 
ELSE 
CASE WHEN Comprobante_Tipo_de_Comprobante = 'egreso' THEN -1*Comprobante_Subtotal WHEN Comprobante_Tipo_de_Comprobante='ingreso' THEN Comprobante_Subtotal END 
END 
FROM facturas_recibidas WHERE Receptor_RFC= 'RFC' AND Emisor_RFC='RFCList' AND Comprobante_Fecha BETWEEN 'srchFechaInicial.SQLDate + " 00:00:00.000' AND 
srchFechaFinal.SQLDate + " 23:59.59.997'
ORDER BY Comprobante_Fecha ASC"
```

As i Said, it works, but can Only returns one column as Result.

But what about if I want to return three columns?
For example: Comprobante_Subtotal, Impuesto and Comprobante_Total and apply the same treatment as Comprobante_subtotal.

I've tried with AND, and splitting by comma unsuccessfully.  :(

Any clues?
Regards

Comment: I am not an english native, I am a latin like you. But I want only to say IMHO that the usage of spanish words for fields and variables names does not help others non latin to find a meaning in your code. So, even if the question could be good, you could have little chanches to have a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CASE cannot result in more than one field-value(column) per row; you'd have to reproduce your logic for each column. An alternative would be to have your logic only performed once, but instead have it result in a "handling" code that can be used in simpler logic in a wrapping query.

It looks like for your scenario, the "handling" code would simply be which multiplier you want to use (-1, 0, 1).

---

```
SELECT @multi := 
   CASE WHEN ValidationSts = 'Cancelado' THEN 0
      WHEN Comprobante_Tipo_de_Comprobante = 'egreso' THEN -1 
      WHEN Comprobante_Tipo_de_Comprobante='ingreso' THEN 1
   END AS multi
   , Comprobante_Subtotal * @multi
   , Impuesto * @multi
   , Comprobante_Total * @multi
FROM facturas_recibidas 
WHERE Receptor_RFC= 'RFC' 
   AND Emisor_RFC='RFCList' 
   AND Comprobante_Fecha BETWEEN [startDatetime] AND [endDatetime]
ORDER BY Comprobante_Fecha ASC;
```

Note: The version above takes advantage of a session variable (@multi) to avoid the need for a subquery. In this case, it should be fine; but some people are averse to them, or find them unreliable. If any of those apply, this can be used to do it without a session variable.

```
SELECT Comprobante_Subtotal * multi
   , Impuesto * multi
   , Comprobante_Total * multi
FROM (
   SELECT 
      CASE WHEN ValidationSts = 'Cancelado' THEN 0
         WHEN Comprobante_Tipo_de_Comprobante = 'egreso' THEN -1 
         WHEN Comprobante_Tipo_de_Comprobante='ingreso' THEN 1
      END AS multi
      , Comprobante_Subtotal, Impuesto, Comprobante_Total
      , Comprobante_Fecha /* subqueries can't guarantee ordering, so this is needed so the outer query can do the final ordering */ 
   FROM facturas_recibidas 
   WHERE Receptor_RFC= 'RFC' 
      AND Emisor_RFC='RFCList' 
      AND Comprobante_Fecha BETWEEN [startDatetime] AND [endDatetime]
) AS subQ
ORDER BY Comprobante_Fecha ASC;
```

---

As a side note, I should point out I got rid of the nested CASE logic; using the `CASE WHEN [condition1] THEN X WHEN [condition2] THEN ....` version instead of the `CASE [switching value] WHEN [value1] THEN X WHEN [value2] THEN ....` makes the nesting unnecessary.